# How to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the inputed address using google geo coder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, google-maps

I want to display the latitude and longitude values in the 2 text boxes when the user enter his address as street, city, state and zipcode. I am using google geocoder.

i have used the following code on button click :

```
   protected void BtnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetLatLongFromAddress(TxtStreet.Text, TxtCity.Text, TxtZipcode.Text,   TxtState.Text);
    }

    private void GetLatLongFromAddress(string street, string city, string zipcode, string state)
    {

        string geocoderUri = string.Format(@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0},{1},{2},{3}&sensor=false", street, city, zipcode, state);


        XmlDocument geocoderXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        geocoderXmlDoc.Load(geocoderUri);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(geocoderXmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("geo", @"http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"); 


        string sLong = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"geo:long", nsMgr).InnerText;
        string sLat = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//geo:lat", nsMgr).InnerText;

        TxtLatitude.Text = sLat;
        TxtLongitude.Text = sLong;
    }
```

But it gets the value of sLong variable as null and shows an error

```
   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

How can i do this ?

waiting for answer...

thnks..

Comment: @AakashM - thanks for reply. Ya i have read it. But i didnt get any idea. how can i use it and which headerfiles should i include ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose I am using excelent GoogleMap control, see details here :

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Google%20Geocoder&referringTitle=Documentation

On this link you have example for server side usage, you can use it from client also, this example is using GeoCoder API to position place on map based on place name.

```
  function DoMapSearch(placeName) {
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    geocoder.getLatLng(placeName, function (point) {
      if (point != null) {
        GoogleMapCnt.loadAddress(addr);
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I have read GoogleMap as you suggested. It is gud. But i want to know how can i add reference to Artem.GoogleGeocoding ?

Comment: download binaries from http://googlemap.codeplex.com/releases/view/52051 and add it as reference in your project

Comment: once again thanks for help. i have to download both the files i.e release and build. ? and i have to add both files in my project ?

Comment: Yuppi..thanks a lot for helping. : ) I have used your way and i got the soloution. But i want to know how can we check if the entered address is wrong and make validation to enter the right address. ?

Comment: on servers side if response.Results array is zero length address is not valid, on client side if address is not valid variable point will be null.

Comment: server side : bool valid = response.Results.Length > 0;

Comment: thanks for helping. i have tried code as - if(response.Results.Length > 0) , but it gives an error that Length property is not supported.. : (

Comment: sorry, try with Count or look at the help

Comment: thanks a lot for helping in getting the solution. And ya finally i tried Count. and i got the solution. : )

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and the error was on the xPath, I changed it to this

```
string sLong = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//geometry/location/lat", nsMgr).InnerText;

string sLat = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"//geometry/location/lng", nsMgr).InnerText;
```

Everything is working fine now.